# The different use of noun modifier

Tags: word-order

The sentence below seems to me to be correct:

> They have the technology that is documented **the best**.

But, can I use a little bit changed sentence as follow:

> They have the technology that is **the best** documented.

Comment: "They have the best documented technology" also works.

Comment: "that is document the best" is not grammatical in English! I'm sorry but I don't understand people saying it is. Not sure the word you want here is documented. They have technology with the best documentation.

Comment: Their technology is the best documented of all the ones I tried.

Comment: I'd suggest a hyphen in your version, @MorganFR.  "The best documented technology" can be read as "the best technology with documentation" instead of "the technology with the best documentation".  The hyphen in "the best-documented technology" guarantees that the adjective applies to the participle.

Comment: "most well-documented" is probably the more common way to say this.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan It is indeed somewhat ambiguous. When spoken, stressing one word or the other will tell you which one you mean. I am not very familiar with making up hyphenated words so I did not want to go any further.

Comment: the OP needs to tell us what he meant: the best technology or the technology with the best documentation.

Comment: The OP examples are not ambiguous.  Marek's "best" definitely applies to "documented", not "technology".  "Documented" and "technology" don't even appear in the same predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the sentences make perfect sense grammatically, but I think the clearest way to write it would be "They have the best documented technology", as it's more streamlined and less awkwardly worded than the other sentences.

Comment: No, /that is documented the best/ is simply not grammatical. X has the best documentation. One can use: best documented technology, ok.

Comment: @Lambie What exactly makes it incorrect? How is it any different from saying "the man who runs the fastest"?

Comment: I'd say that it may sound kind of awkward, but I don't think there's anything grammatically wrong with it.

Comment: For me, it is not native speaker of English usage at all. You might say: "They have the technology that is documented the best" but you would not write it.

Comment: I agree that it's bad writing, but is still doesn't make it grammatically incorrect, just clunky.

Comment: The grammar of spoken English is not the grammar of written English. That's my position.